# Swap/invert the order bold not-bold bold not-bold // to // not-bold bold not-bold bold

Tags: replace, ms-word, wildcard

I can't figure out how to swap/invert these... I have:

**H34** Today is  **H3** going to be  **H8314** warm!  **H22** Nice,  **H831** sunny  **H5921** and  **H6** a beautiful  **H815** day?  **H730** So  **H43** I  **H1** will  **H921** go  **H6440** outside  **H4325** once again.

But I need first the words (some are phrases) and then the numbering system (seen in Bold), like this:

Today is **H34** going to be  **H3** warm! **H8314** Nice, **H22** sunny **H831** and **H5921** a beautiful **H6** day? **H815** So  **H730** I  **H43** will  **H1**  go **H921** outside  **H6440** once again. **H4325**

The good thing is, in my docx file, the wording is always "not Bold" and the numbering system is always "Bold".
I would prefer to do it in MS Word 2010 if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question comes out weird-looking, but I think I understand you.  The key is to realize that the replace function can do search/replace on formatting.  So, search for bold and replace it with italic.  Then search for not-bold and not-italic, and replace it with bold.  Then search for italic and replace it with bold.  (I am assuming you have only bold and not-bold, with no italics, in the original.)

Comment: H34 Today is H3 going to be

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping.

Acutally I need to invert "H34 Today is" (first the H code, then the phrase) flip it to read "Today is H34" (first the phrase and then the H code) because it's a numbering system so I need it tagged after the phrase, because eventually it will appear as a superscript reference, thus, it goes after each phrase.
Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, then you're going to need a macro, no getting around it.  Fortunately for you, the bold text is always one word.  I think the following algorithm will work.  Step 0: Start at the END of the document, and work backwards.  Step 1: Find (to the left) non-bold text, and cut it all out.  (If the find fails, stop, you're done.)  Step 2: Find (to the right) a bold word, and paste your non-bold text to the right of that bold word.  Now you'll have two bold words in a row.  Step 3: Go to step 1.